# How to get size of floating toolbar

Tags: mfc

How do I get the size of a floating `CControlBar` in MFC?
I want to obtain a size in **screen** coordinates.

I have tried

```
CControlBar *bar_p;
...
bar_p->GetWindowRect(&rect);
```

which doesn't seem to include the borders, and

```
bar_p->GetParent()->GetParent()->GetWindowRect(&rect);
```

which gives a size that is a little too wide and tall.

Comment: I know the sizes are wrong, because after measuring, I rearrange the windows according to these sizes and call

  FloatControlBar(bar_p, CPoint(x, y));
but the windows are placed too far apart

Comment: Maybe you can fine some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165416/mfc-sizing-a-docked-toolbar-using-ccontrolbaronnccalcsize-receives-wrong-valu

Comment: This is in response to a user command, so the window sizes will have been updated by this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a bug elsewhere in the program. The following does indeed find the rectangle of the CMiniFrameWnd in which the floating toolbar appears

```
CRect rect;
if(bar_p->IsFloating())
{
 bar_p->GetParent()->GetParent()->GetWindowRect(&rect);
 ..
}
```